# закрыть IE с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

что нужно прописать в консоли чтобы браузер сразу закрылся?

моя попытка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это максимум из возможного.

Comment: Вроде как нельзя. Впрочем, может какие лазейки в IE ещё остались - всё-таки он довольно старый.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.open('','_self').close();
```

Comment: у меня была мысль получить PID процесса как-то и убивать процесс, но благодаря вам я не буду разбираться как :)

Comment: `javascript:` тут лишний. А так, проверил на IE11 в Win7 - работает.

Comment: @sevnight, до pid ты из js точно не докопаешься. К тому же, у IE все вкладки в одном процессе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в моём случае докопаюсь, ибо я использую js в батнике)